# How do I sort repeater field alphabetically? ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm wanting to display a names of users list and order them alphabetically by the users name. How can I do this?
I am asking for help in solving this problem:

```
<?php if(get_field('sign_up',  'options')): ?>

<ul>

<?php while(has_sub_field('sign_up',  'options')): ?>

    <li><?php the_sub_field('your_name', 'options'); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You will get a detailed answer in the official documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, making us of the array_multisort() function:

```
<?php // Get repeater value
$repeater = get_field('sign_up',  'options');

// Obtain list of columns
foreach ($repeater as $key => $row) {
    $the_name[$key] = $row['your_name'];
}

// Sort the data by name column, ascending
array_multisort($the_name, SORT_ASC, $repeater);?>

<?php if($repeater): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('sign_up',  'options')): ?>
            <?php foreach( $repeater as $row ) { // Display newly orded columns ?>
                <li><?php echo $row['your_name'];?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I add the first name it's okay. But when I add the second name position then these 2 items are duplicated (4 items). When I add the third item, 9 elements are displayed. Do you know why?

Comment: Try removing the if and while statements as I think it’s causing issues.